# How to convert the object back to an array?

Tags: php, php-5.3, stdclass

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013143/how-to-access-the-property-value-of-an-array-which-has-been-converted-into-an-o), I use this function to convert arrays to objects,

```
function array_to_object($array)
{
    if(!is_array($array)) {
        return $array;
    }

    $object = new stdClass();
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = (string) $key ;
        $object->$key = is_array($value) ? array_to_object($value) : $value;
    }
    return $object;
}
```

So,

```
$obj =  array('qualitypoint', 'technologies', 'India');
```

result,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => qualitypoint
    [1] => technologies
    [2] => India
)
```

But now I need to convert the object back to an array so that I can get this result,

```
Array
(
    [0] => qualitypoint
    [1] => technologies
    [2] => India
)
```

is it possible?

Comment: Then why turn it into an object in the first place? You can still get your values out of your $obj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to achieve this is:

```
$array = array(json_decode(json_encode($object), true));
```

When I tested, I had no problems with inaccessible properties.

**Update:** It also works with

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->{0} = 'qualitypoint';
$object->{1} = 'technologies';
$object->{2} = 'India';
```

Comment: He wants an array not an Object again

Comment: Yes, I meant that the stdClass in above code is the object that you have as input.

@Iauthiamkok would you accept my answer if you are using this solution?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Be aware that for string properties, **they must be encoded in UTF-8** or this method will not work.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the advice. Can you give some example when this code won't work? How can I make sure that `they must be encoded in UTF-8`? Thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php): *This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data* (otherwise it returns `null` and the method fails). If it is not already UTF-8 you have to change the encoding, e.g. with `iconv`.

Answer (score 3):

### What would be nice, but will not really work as it is

Normally a good starting approach is to simply [cast the object to array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting):

```
$arr = (array) $obj;
```

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose
>   elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
>   names, with a few notable exceptions: **integer properties are
>   unaccessible**; private variables have the class name prepended to the
>   variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the
>   variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

Unfortunately this will not work for you because the properties have "integer" names.

---

A variation on the above is [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
$arr = get_object_vars($obj);
```

One important point here is that `get_object_vars` respects visibility, which means that it will **only** give you the public properties of `$obj` since you are not calling it from within a method of `$obj`.

However this will also not work in this case: `get_object_vars` will also not give you integer-named properties.

### What will work (but is not nice)

[Iterating over an object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) will also give you the *visible* properties it has (only `public` properties in this case), but it will also process properties with integer names:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($obj as $k => $v) {
    $arr[$k] = $v;
}
```